# Understanding Behaviour of Find method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, higher-order-functions

```
let arr = [{ age: 3 }, { age: 5 }, { age: 6 }, { age: 7 }];
let exists = arr.find(x => x.age < 4);
exists.age += 1;
console.log(arr);

//output is [{age:4},{age:5},{age:6},{age:7}];
```

In the above example, I'm updating the result returned by the find method but it also changes the value of the original array why so?

Comment: remove `exists.age += 1;`

Comment: coz your modifying object... `exists.age += 1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because Objects in JavaScript are passed by reference, you got that object      ( {age : 3} ) in exists then added 1 to it's "age" key , so the original object also changed .

```js
let obj1 = {age: 3 , name: 'jack' }
let obj2 = obj1

console.log(obj1 === obj2 )  // true

// if you change the second object , the first one will change too :

obj2.age = 15

console.log(obj1 , obj2 )  

// obj1 = { age: 15 , name: 'jack' } 
// obj2 = { age: 15 , name: 'jack' }
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) will return the first element that satisfy the condition that you've passed as a callback function.

Since you are looking for an object whose `age` property is less than `4`. So It will return first object(whose `age` is `3`). So if you gonna check for equality of `exists` and `arr[0]` then It will return object that satisfy the condition

```js
let arr = [{ age: 3 }, { age: 5 }, { age: 6 }, { age: 7 }];
let exists = arr.find((x) => x.age < 4);

console.log(exists === arr[0])
```

So, If you are going to do any kind of mutation with the object that is returned by the `find` method then the original object will reflect the changes.

Because both are same object just different references.

---

If you don't want to mutate the original object then you should clone it before doing any kind of changes to that object.

**`Note: Both of the following method does shallow copy`**

**1)** Using [`spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
let arr = [{ age: 3 }, { age: 5 }, { age: 6 }, { age: 7 }];
let exists = arr.find((x) => x.age < 4);

const clone = { ...exists };
clone.age += 1;
console.log(arr);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**2)** Using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
let arr = [{ age: 3 }, { age: 5 }, { age: 6 }, { age: 7 }];
let exists = arr.find((x) => x.age < 4);

const clone = Object.assign({}, exists);
clone.age += 1;
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have an array of object references. In JavaScript, objects are actually stored elsewhere (called the "heap") and object variables actually only contain the *references* to object. So the reason is because you're updating the same object.

If you want to do a shallow clone of an object, you can use `Object.assign({}, obj)`.

Further, not directly relevant to your question, if your object properties *themselves* were to contain other object references, including arrays, and you want those to be copies as well, you'll have to deep-clone them. This is not automatically done by a stock JavaScript function or method. You'll have to find code that does that for you or write it yourself. Last time I did this, I used randa's clone function because a different developer on my team had already imported the ramda library into our project. What makes the most sense for your project may be different.